# How to avoid concurrent Modification and NoElementException altogether - RealmList android

Tags: android, realm

Im having issue with RealmList, as per checking the source its using RealmList as the receiver of the response. But after i iterate these items that i need to remove I got ConcurrentModification Exception and then later I added some fix using Iterator now I got NoElementException.

## 1

```
RealmList<SomeObject> list = ...
for (SomeObject object : list){
  if (object.isSomethingElse){
     list.remove(object); // Concurrent Modification Exception
  }

}
```

## 2

```
RealmList<SomeObject> list = ...
for (Iterator<SomeObject> objectIterator = list.iterator ; list.hasNext();){
  SomeObject object = objectIterator.next(); // NoSuchElementException
  if (object.isSomethingElse){
     objectIterator.remove(object); 
  }

}
```

**Right now what i did to proceed is, before accepting the response from BE, I now filtered it.**

How do I mitigate this issue?

Comment: You *might* want to post some relevant code that can help us understand how you ran into this issue

Comment: `objectIterator.remove(object);` i don't think there is such a method?